# SFMC Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is there a way to upload the images and get the personalised link? I have 60 images, but when I upload the images in the content builder, it does not create the personalised link.

So this becomes difficult to manage.

When we used to have portfolio, I can get the personalised link for the images.

Thanks
Chandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure, that Predictable File URLs are enabled under:

**Setup** > **Feature Settings** > **Content Builder** > **Content Builder Settings**

[image: Content Builder Predictable File URLs]

This will allow you to provide the filename when uploading the image to Content Builder (remember to click on Options):
[image: Custom file name in upload]
Also, when using API, one can provide the filename in the payload to the asset REST endpoint of Content Builder API:

https://TENNANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets

```json
{
    "fileName": "Personalised_name.png",
    "assetType": {
        "name": "png",
        "id": 28
    },
    "file": "[Your file data goes here]",
    "category": {
        "id": "[Folder ID]"
    },
    "FileProperties": {
        "fileName": "Personalised_name.png"
    }
}
```